# Can I get markdown file's contents in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can get the contents of a .txt file in this way:

```
NSString *articlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@".txt"];
return [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:articlePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

However,it is no use when the file is a markdown file:

```
NSString *articlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test2" ofType:@".md"];
return [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:articlePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The `articlePath` is "nil",but the file is exist actually.

I wonder if there any method I can use to get the contents of a .md file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to : Target -> "Build Phases" -> "copy bundle Resources" Then add that particular file here.

Make sure that test2 file is there [image]

Comment: Yeah,you are right.But I'm still confused about why .txt file is added in automaticly but .md file not.

Comment: When you add resources, make sure not only the copy items into destination group's folder (if needed) is ticked, but also tick the corresponding target in the Add to targets list.